# Set up data pipeline for video processing

Tags: python, tensorflow, data-science, tensorflow-datasets

I am newbie to Tensorflow so I would appreciate any constructive help.

I am trying to build a feature extraction and data pipeline with Tensorflow for video processing where multiple folders holding video files with multiple classes (JHMDB database), but kind of stuck.

I have the feature extracted to one folder, at the moment to separate *.npz compressed arrays, in the filename I have stored the class name as well.

#### First Attempt

First I thought I would use this code from the TF tutorials site, simply reading files from folder method:

```
jhmdb_path = Path('...')


# Process files in folder
list_ds = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(str(jhmdb_path/'*.npz'))

for f in list_ds.take(5):
    print(f.numpy())

def process_path(file_path):
    labels = tf.strings.split(file_path, '_')[-1]
    features = np.load(file_path)

    return features, labels

labeled_ds = list_ds.map(process_path)

for a, b in labeled_ds.take(5):
    print(a, b)

TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not Tensor
```

..but this not working.

#### Second Attempt

Then I thought ok I will use generators:

```
# using generator
jhmdb_path = Path('...')

def generator():
    for item in jhmdb_path.glob("*.npz"):
        features = np.load(item)
        print(item.files)
        print(f['PAFs'].shape)
        features = features['PAFs']

        yield features

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(generator, (tf.uint8))
iter(next(dataset))

TypeError: 'FlatMapDataset' object is not an iterator...not working.
```

In the first case, somehow the path is a byte type, and I could not change it to `str` to be able to load it with `np.load()`. (If I point a file directly on `np.load(direct_path)`, then strange, but it works.)

At second case...  I am not sure what is wrong.

I looked for hours to find a solution how to build an iterable dataset from list of relatively big and large numbers of 'npz' or 'npy' files, but seems to be this is not mentioned anywhere (or just way too trivial maybe).

Also, as I could not test the model so far, I am not sure if this is the good way to go.  I.e. to feed the model with hundreds of files in this way, or just build one huge 3.5 GB npz (that would sill fit in memory) and use that instead. Or use TFrecords, but that looks more complicated, than the usual examples.

What is really annoying here, that TF tutorials and in general all are about how to load a ready dataset directly, or how to load `np` array(s) or how to load, image, text, dataframe objects, but no way to find any real examples how to process big chunks of data files, e.g. the case of extracting features from audio or video files.

So any suggestions or solutions would be highly appreciated and I would be really, really grateful to have something finally working! :)